# Sveltekit Post Request how to return a Response Object with non blocking database access?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I'm trying to send a POST request to a +server.js endpoint that saves the data to the database without blocking my code from execution

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function POST({ request }) {

    request.json()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("data: ", data);
            getConnection()
                .then((conn) => {
                    let sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, socialMediaPlatform, accountLink) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    let result = conn.query(sql, [data.username, data.password, data.socialMediaPlatform, data.accountLink]);
                    conn.release();

                    return new Response(JSON.stringify(result), {
                        status: 200,
                    });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return new Response(JSON.stringify({error: err}), {
                    status: 400,
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return new Response(JSON.stringify({error: err}), {
                status: 400,
            });
        });
}
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid response from route /api/account: handler should return a Response object
```

But it somehow works and writes the data to the database.

Bonusquestion:
I'm also getting this errormessage from vscode when hovering over the POST function
Shouldn't this be typescript specific?
And shouldn't the error only come if
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually returning anything, as all the `return` statements are inside functions. You have to add a return at the very start (`return request.json()...`) and before `getConnection` or [use `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) instead of chaining (which I would recommend).

TS can check JS as well, there are the flags [`allowJs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs) and [`checkJs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy understandable answer!